Discrepancy in area calculation between pyproj1 and pyproj2
I am wondering if anyone else has come across this difference when changing from pyproj 1 to pyproj 2 as described in the FAQ's:
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1
I am transforming from "EPSG:4326" to "aea" and although the method works, I am getting a completely different .area attribute value when running the same .kml with each implementation (1 and 2).
Could someone please advise as to what has changed to make this happen?
